# Why is this java code not opening text file?

Tags: java, file

I am attempting to open a file (words.txt) and then count the number of vowels inside. Here is my code:

```
        Scanner input = new Scanner("words.txt");
    String fileContent = "";

    while (input.hasNext()) {

        fileContent += input.next() + " ";
    }
   input.close();

    char[] charArr = fileContent.toCharArray();
    int counter = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < charArr.length; i++)

    {
          if(charArr[i] == 'a' || charArr[i] == 'e' || charArr[i] == 'i' || charArr[i] == 'o' || charArr[i] == 'u')

               counter++;
    }

  System.out.println(fileContent);
```

When I print the filecontent variable, it is telling me the string it is holding is 'words.txt'. Its not actually opening the file, just reading the name of it. Thoughts?

Comment: Did you read the javadoc for `Scanner`?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html - Take a look at the constructor summary.

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`Scanner` constructor that takes a `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-), but it just reads from the `String` directly.

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified string.

You should create a `File` from your filename and pass the `File` to another [`Scanner` constructor that takes a `File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.io.File-):

> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the specified file.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The Scanner class takes a string; you never give it contents of an actual file.

Answer (score 0):

try this

File file = new File("word.txt");
then open the file in scnner

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use **regex** for your pattern matching instead of your if solution:

```
int counter = 0;        

try (final Scanner in = new Scanner(Paths.get("src/words.txt"))) {
    in.useDelimiter("[aeiouAEIOU]");

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        in.next()
        counter++;
    }
}

System.out.println("Number of vowels: " + (counter - 1));
```

Or for a little shorter version, use a **for-loop**:

```
...
for (counter = 0; in.hasNext(); in.next(), counter++) {
    //do additional stuff like counting for statistics eg.
}
...
```